# Configuring Python Virtual Environment to use Python 3

Tags: python, django, virtual-environment

I am learning Django. I installed two different versions of python on my laptop, 2 and 3. I configured my Laptop to use Python 3, so when I check version using the command line, I got this output.

[image]

Then, I installed the Django and Python Virtual Environment following [this link](https://djangobook.com/installing-django/). I could install the Django and Virtual Environment successfully. But my virtual environment is using the python 2. When I check the version in the virtual environment, I got this output.

[image]

So, how can I configure that virtual environment to use python 3 instead of 2? Or how can I set the Python version to be used when I set up the Environment for the Django?

Comment: This was answered before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: try `virtualenv -p python3`

Comment: And even better: try `pipenv --three`

Comment: @WaiYanHein, I have added an answer to your questions. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualenv with python 2

```
virtualenv myEnv
```

Virtualenv with python 3

```
virtualenv -p python3 myEnv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux just use the command `python3 -m venv myvenv` in the directory of your project and you're done!

Comment: What about windows?

Comment: @flpn, he is definitely using Windows... see the images.

Answer (score 0):

Execute below command line:->

**For Python3** :->

```
virtualenv --python = $(which python3) EnvironmentName
```

**For Python2** :->

```
virtualenv --python = $(which python) EnvironmentName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Python 3, the recommended way to create a virtual environment is using `python3 -m venv` as follows:

```
python3 -m venv venv # this will create a virtual environment called venv
```

In your case, you can directly use `python` instead of `python3` since you have already configured your laptop to use Python 3 when running `python` (this is shown in your question).

In Windows, to activate this virtual environment run the following:

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

That's it!